# Adding extra rows of same data based on data within two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there an efficient way to add missing data to one of temp tables based on joining with another table, using pure sql.

Here is a very simplified example:

```js
declare @t1 table (LocId int, ItemId int, SomeData nvarchar(max))
insert into @t1 VALUES (1, 1111, 'x')
insert into @t1 VALUES (2, 1111, 'x')
insert into @t1 VALUES (2, 2222, 'x')

select * from @t1

declare @t2 table (LocId int)
insert into @t2 VALUES(1)
insert into @t2 VALUES(2)

select * from @t2

select * from @t1 t1
left join @t2 t2 on t1.LocId = t2.LocId
```

Here is the result:
[image]

In this specific example, I would like to come up with a query that would join the two temp tables, and add a missing location with same data for 'Item' 2222. So, I have two locations in one of my temp tables (1,2), in my another temp table I have the two locations for Item 1111, but only one location (2) for ItemId 2222. I am looking for a join/query that would add additional row, with the same data (just different, that new Loc). In my example a new row would be (1,2222,x). Is something like that even doable?

And to be more specific, here is an image:

[image]

We have 4 different locations, and only the first SKU is populated with these 4 locations. Because there is no data in the database for other SKU (in this example), I would like to populate all other SKUs with missing Locations. Obviously there is more columns involved.

Here is what it should output:

[image]

Comment: please tag the database

Comment: can you please do a proper example.

Comment: Not at all clear what you are trying to do here. Great job posting sample data though. What is the desired output for the sample data?

Answer (score 0):

```
with
   locations as (select distinct LocId from T),
   items as (select distinct ItemId from T)
select l.LocId, i.ItemId, t.SomeData
from
   locations as l cross join items as i
   left outer join T as t
       on t.LocId = l.LocId and t.ItemId = i.ItemId;
```

Comment: This is almost great, the only thing is the missing rows are populated with NULLS. Is there a way to populate it with the already existing data for corresponding ItemId

Comment: Also, I have tested it with 10k rows, it is not that efficient, great idea though, looks like what I am after is not possible. thank you

Comment: Well if you have separate tables and items it might be a lot faster. And of course there's also indexing to consider. I'm not really sure what data you want populated in place of nulls.